# Preventing an expression attribute from compiling, so it is passed as a string between nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a directive (I'll call it the *parent* directive) that uses another directive (*child* directive). I'd like the parent directive to delegate an attribute that contains an expression **as a string**, so the child directive attach to the expression the right scope.

## HTML

My simplified markup is as follows:

```
<my-select option-template = '{{name}}' />
```

The important thing to note here is that `{{name}}` expression will be used by the child directive with the correct scope, but `{{name}}` isn't on the current scope (of the parent, my-select directive). Thus, I wish the `my-select` (parent) directive to simply see it as a string and delegate that string to the child directive.

## The parent directive

The strip-down parent directive looks like so:

```
.directive('mySelect', function () {
    template: '<myOption option-template = "[X]" />'
}
```

Where `[X]` means 'the same value as the option-template attribute given to you; ie, `{{name}}`.

## The child directive

Then on the child directive, a similar thing should happen: `{{name}}` should be treated as a string that will be attached the right scope during linking.

The child directive should look something like this:

```
.directive('myOption', function () {
    template: '<div>The name is: [Y]</div>'
}
```

Where [Y] means 'whatever you got on the `option-template` attribute.

## The issue

My main issue is that as soon I introduce and expression in an attribute, the compiler compiles it, and there is not way for me to delegate it to the child directive as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after quite few attempt, one can define a directive for the `template` attribute like so:

```
cbUI.directive( 'optionTemplate', function( $compile ) {
    return {
        compile: function compile( tElement, tAttributes ) {

            // String-replace the {{optionTemplate}} string with the actual value
            // of the attribute provided.
            var iOptionTemplate = tAttributes.optionTemplate;           
            var iHTML = tElement.html();            
            iHTML = iHTML.replace('{{optionTemplate}}', iOptionTemplate );            
            tElement.html( iHTML );

            return function postLink( scope, element, attributes ) { };
        }        
    }
});
```

Then any other directive can use template as normal, as if the attribute is in the scope:

```
.directive('mySelect', function () {
    template: '<myOption option-template="{{optionTemplate}}" />'
}
```